# Demand with different Measurement

Tags: self-study, variance, standard-deviation, expected-value

Weekly's demand of a product has a probability function

```
Demand, x   Probability (fx)
------------------------
0           0,1
1           025
2           0,4
3           0,15
4           0,10
5 or more   0
```

I have difficult to find out the

- expected value,
- variance and
- standard deviation

for the weekly demand.

Where should I start?

Comment: A *definition* is usually a good place to begin. What definition(s) do you know for expectation, variance, and SD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the expected value is

$$
E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n{x_if(x_i)}
$$

the variance is

$$
Var(X) = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-E[X])^2f(x_i)
$$

and the standard deviation is

$$
\sigma = \sqrt{Var(x)}
$$

All you have to do is plug in your numbers.

As always, wikipedia or google are your friends with these types of questions. This being a self-study question I might've given away too much but except posting a link to wikipedia (a bit too superficial) I don't think I could've done anything else. Good with your studies and have fun.